How does STM32 know if I'm using SWD or JTAG
My curiosity got the best of me so I'm hoping someone here can help educate me. I'm using a STM32 (STM32F101C8Tx to be precise), which supports both JTAG and SWD. Within STM32CubeIDE I can switch between these options to configure the pins; however, from a cold boot, how does the microcontroller know which protocol is being used by the programmer/debugger? My assumption is that it monitors the JTAG TMS / SWDIO pin for specific signals but I've not managed to find any reference.

"I've not managed to find any reference" Always go to the source: ADIv6.0. Part B5.2 has detailed description of switching mechanism between SWD and JTAG.

Also, pay attention to the pin descriptions in chip datasheet. JTAG/SWD pins usually configured as alternate functions on reset, with internal pull-ups and pull-downs activated to prevent unexpected behavior. Cube configuration kicks in much later than that. For example, if you put a LED on JTRST pin, connect it to Vcc rather than GND, because that pin has pull-up on reset.

JTAG typically uses more pins for communication, while SWD uses only two pins: SWDIO (Serial Wire Debug I/O) and SWCLK (Serial Wire Clock).

The MCU expects JTAG signals by default so to use SWD the debug interface needs a current interface reset sequence (more than 50 clocks with data high) and then you send a 16-bit command sequence to transition from JTAG to SWD mode, and send the 50 clocks again to reset the current interface. The sequence works so that it does not matter if the MCU was expecting JTAG or already put into SWD mode, it will end up in SWD mode and be reset to expect the first command in SWD mode.

Debug port that supports both SWD and JTAG is named "SWJ-DP" in ARM documents. You'll find a complete specification for debug ports in ARM's IHI 0031 "Arm Debug Interface Architecture Specification ADIv5.0 to ADIv5.2".
The switching method is explained in chapter B5.2 "Switching between SWD and JTAG".
It basically involves doing a SWDIOTMS sequence that:

moves DP to reset state (with a sequence that has this effect with either SWD and JTAG),
perform a well-known fixed SWDIOTMS sequence that has no side effect when you decode it in the perspective of either protocols,
perform usual DP init sequence in "destination" mode.

SWD-to-JTAG and JTAG-to-SWD sequences may be performed even on non-SWJ-DP ports and still be harmless.

Thank you for the more complete breakdown. Understanding how this works is really helpful and I appreciate the feedback.
